# Apply foreign key restrictions in EER

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, reverse-engineering

Only persons from the same country should be allowed to chat together. How can I achieve this using an ERM?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do this in the database you will check if the players are in the same country using your programming language.

Comment: @ChristophBühler Your ERM is wron because you can't say player_one and player_two in the same row(Table Team) read my edit pls. And no my database does what you want.

Comment: My teams always have two players. This is not about basketball haha. Therefore, I think my ERM is legit.

Comment: @ChristophBühler it doesen't matter if it is about basketball or not. And no your erm isn't legit the basketball thing was a example but where will you use this database?

Comment: This is a sample table.

Comment: @ChristophBühler insn't your question answered?

Comment: It is answered. Could you remove everything beside "You don't do this in the database you will check if the players are in the same country using your programming language."? I appreicate your effort!

Comment: Good, thanks. I've edited the question a little. Maybe this is a better sample.